# Why does my HWID lock accept any value in acceptedSerial_2

Tags: c++, winapi, command-line-interface

Basically im using a HWID lock to lock my program but im having an issue where my program accepts any value in acceptedSerial_2
Here is the code, please help me make improvements, Thank you!
Obviously when i run the program the accepted serials are not 0, theyre the respected values

````
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 12);
        std::cout << ":: Verifying HWID \n " << std::endl;
        TCHAR volumeName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
        TCHAR fileSystemName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
        DWORD serialNumber = 0;
        DWORD maxComponentLen = 0;
        DWORD fileSystemFlags = 0;
        if (GetVolumeInformation(
            _T("C:\\"),
            volumeName,
            ARRAYSIZE(volumeName),
            &serialNumber,
            &maxComponentLen,
            &fileSystemFlags,
            fileSystemName,
            ARRAYSIZE(fileSystemName)))
        {

            DWORD acceptedSerial = 0; // 
            DWORD acceptedSerial_1 = 0; //
            DWORD acceptedSerial_2 = 0; // 


            if (serialNumber == acceptedSerial || acceptedSerial_1 || acceptedSerial_2)
            {
                MessageBox::Show("Access Granted!",
                    "Welcome",
                    MessageBoxButtons::OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon::Exclamation);
                return(0);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox::Show("HWID Missmatch",
                    "Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons::OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon::Error);
                exit(0);
            }


        }

    }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to accept only three values: `acceptedSerial`, `acceptedSerial_1`, `acceptedSerial_2`, then the logical expression will be `if ((serialNumber == acceptedSerial) || (serialNumber == acceptedSerial_1) || (serialNumber == acceptedSerial_2))` .

However, the one you currently use: `if (serialNumber == acceptedSerial || acceptedSerial_1 || acceptedSerial_2)` always is `true` as long as `acceptedSerial_1`  or `acceptedSerial_2` is not zero even if they are not equal to `serialNumber`.

Refer to [C++ Logical OR operator: ||](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/logical-or-operator-pipe-pipe?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Thank you so much, this has helped me understand